# itinerary: making double array String into a Map of String, String (Key & Value)

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, data-structures

I have a `String[][]`. So it basically looks like this:

```
{
  { "Dublin", "NYC"},
  { "Moscow", "Los-Angeles"},
  { "London", "Paris" }
}
```

And I have to add them to `Map`, so that Keys will be first column(Dublin, Moscow, London), and Values will be second (NYC, LA, Paris)

Can you please help, I don't know where to start

Answer (score 1):

Create map

> `HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();`

Loop over **data** ( String[][]).
Each array in data is your key and value.
Add them to map

```
for (String[] keyValue : data) {
   map.put(keyValue[0],keyValue[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add this array elements into a `Map`, you just need to use a loop to iterate over all the `key, value` pairs and add them to the a **[Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)**.

This is how should be your code:

```
String[][] array = { { "Dublin", "NYC"}, { "Moscow", "Los-Angeles"}, { "London", "Paris" }};
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

//loop over the array and add elements into the HashMap
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
   map.put(array[i][0], array[i][1]);
}
```

This is [a live **working Demo**](https://ideone.com/AqKnsN).

Answer (score 0):

The same with java Streams:

```
String[][] array = { { "Dublin", "NYC"}, { "Moscow", "Los-Angeles"}, { "London", "Paris" }};
Map<String, String> flightsMap = Stream.of(array)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p[0], p -> p[1]));
```